# How can I induce failure from std::env::current_dir()?

Tags: linux, unit-testing, testing, rust, directory

I am creating a function that will check the current directory at some point. From the signature, [`current_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) can return an error and I want to test the case it does. However I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Here's my code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7d8ed377d2b89521e3fd2736dae383a)):

```rust
use std::env;
 
#[allow(unused)]
fn check_current_dir() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    if let Ok(current_dir) = env::current_dir() {
        println!("Current dir is ok: {:?}", current_dir);
        return Ok(());
    } else {
        return Err("Currentdir failed");
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod check_current_dir {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn current_dir_fail() {
        assert!(check_current_dir().is_ok()) // want to make it fail
    }
}
```

I tried creating a directory, moving the current directory to it, and removing that directory, but that failed. I tried using a symlink directory, but `current_dir()` still returned `Ok(_)`. This is designed to run on Linux if that matters.

Does any one have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage of `getcwd` which `current_dir` uses on Unix these are the possible failures:

```
ERRORS
       EACCES Permission to read or search a component of the filename was denied.

       ENAMETOOLONG
              getwd(): The size of the null-terminated absolute pathname string exceeds PATH_MAX bytes.

       ENOENT The current working directory has been unlinked.

       ENOMEM Out of memory.
```

From wich I excluded `EFAULT`, `EINVAL` and `ERANGE` since Rusts `std` is handling `buf` and `size` for you.
So for example this test which removes the current directory will fail:

```rust
use std::fs;

use super::*;

#[test]
fn current_dir_fail() {
    fs::create_dir("bogus").unwrap();
    std::env::set_current_dir("bogus").unwrap();
    fs::remove_dir("../bogus").unwrap();
    assert!(check_current_dir().is_ok()) //want to make it fail
}
```

But with your current implementation of `check_current_dir`, that's essentially testing `std` which is well tested and you shouldn't need to do it.

Comment: Oh thanks! That's worked. I thought I have tried this, but maybe not. Thanks!